# Tool for export to JSON from ArangoDB

Tags: json, export, arangodb

To create a native backup and restore it, one has to use `arangodump` and `arangorestore`.

To import from JSON (and CSV, TSV), one has to use `arangoimp`.

What can I use to **export to JSON** from ArangoDB?

Comment: How many documents are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use the arangodump tool that is shipped with ArangoDB.
It can be used to dump an entire database or individual collections. It stores dumped data in JSON format on disk.
Maybe arangodump's output already is in a format that you can work with.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the data from the arangodump JSON. However, I'm having issues resolving revisions ("_rev") in order to determine the latest versions of documents. How did you guys resolve this?

I also asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604089/arangodump-how-do-i-know-the-latest-revision